# element will not display at 100% height

Tags: html, css

On the following webpage http://rocoru.com/web/course.html on line 91 the following HTML

```
<li><strong>Description</strong></li>
```

doesn't display at 100% height with the following CSS applied to it:

```
li strong {
width: 35%;
float: left;
height: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

What are potential reasons why this element would not equal the height of the < li> tag with the CSS shown above applied to it?

Comment: Have you looked at the structure of your whole CSS? Maybe one selector is overriding...

Answer (score -2):

The Problem is in

```
<div>Il y a des petites fees au creux de ma main et qui prennent le the dans un jardin. Il y a des petites fees au creux de ma main et qui prennent le the dans un jardin</div>
```

You Used to much text..

try changing it to

`<div> test text </div>` and see the difference :)

hope it helps

Comment: then change the font size less than the average size

Comment: It'll look like crap. He could set a fixed `line-height` then set the `overflow` to `hidden` with a few other adjustments, but shortening a "description" to a few words is hard to visualize.

Comment: then change the paddings of the <li> larger if you dont want to change the font sizes :)